# .htaccess redirect folder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, subdomain

I've tried applying a few of the answers found on stackoverflow, but either I'm missing something or I'm plain dumb.

Basically I got a main domain name. This domain already has a non-www redirect. So http://domain.com becomes http://www.domain.com. This domain also has a mobile version found inside the the 'm' folder. So accessing the domain name like http://www.domain.com/m/ works and so does http://m.domain.com. What I'm trying to achieve is simple: anyone whom goes to the site via http://www.domain.com/m/, or http://www.domain.com/m/about should be redirected to the subdomain version so to http://m.domain.com or http://m.domain.com/about in the second case listed above.

Whatever I tried implementing ended up with errors, either I managed to disable direct access to m.domain.com, but it worked via domain.com/m/, or redirect loops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `domain.com` main .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ http://m.%1/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

# non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m|www)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: thanks mate for your reply. Your code works perfectly for the mobile version, however I lost the non-www to www redirect. Any idea why? I'm only using the code you wrote above. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your update, but it didn't work as expected :(. Basically the non-www to www is okay, but the mobile version now adds a `www`, something that I don't need and it also adds a trailing `/m/` after the domain extensions and also redirects to the subdomain, so I'm getting a `http://www.m.domain.com/m/` and I'd need it to be `http://m.domain.com`

Comment: thanks again for taking your time mate, but it's not working as expected. The above code didn't redirect the non-www link and on top of that it was adding an extra `www` if I was linking to absolute URLs within the site :(

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, fixed it now. Try my updated rule now after clearing your browser cache.